# How to read $f^{-1}(f(x))$?

Tags: calculus

I was listening to an some video where it pronounced $f^{-1}(f(x))$ as "the inverse of $f$ of $x$" which matches exactly the pronunciation of $f^{-1}(x))$. What are the possible phrases for pronouncing $f^{-1}(f(x))$?

Comment: I would pronounce it as "the inverse of $f(x)$ applied to $f(x)$".

Comment: Or the inverse of $f$ applied to $f(x)$, or the inverse of $f$ at $f(x)$.

Comment: Is $f$ a bijection? Otherwise the notation $f^{-1}(y)$ does not refer to the inverse but to the preimage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f\colon X\to Y$ is a bijection with inverse $f^{-1}$ you might read "$f^{-1}(f(x))$" as

- $f$ inverse of $f$ of $x$,
- the inverse of $f$ applied to $f$ of $x$, or
- the image of $f$ of $x$ under the inverse of $f$.

If $f$ is not a bijection, the notation $f^{-1}(y)$ is often used to denote the preimage
$$
f^{-1}(y) = f^{-1}(\{y\}) = \{\, x\in X \mid f(x) =y \,\}
$$
and you would read "$f^{-1}(f(x))$" as

- the preimage of $f$ of $x$ under $f$,
- the fiber of $f$ of $x$ under $f$,

or also, misusing the phrase "$f$ inverse" despite $f$ not being bijective, as "$f$ inverse of $f$ of $x$", just reading the symbols almost verbatim.

Answer (score 2):

Reading $f^{-1}(f(x))$ as "the inverse of $f$ at $x$" is not correct. That would refer to $f^{-1}(x)$. A slight variation is correct: "the inverse of $f$ at $f$ of $x$". If $f$ is not a bijection, then say "the fiber of $f$ at $f$ of $x$" rather than using the word "inverse".